# Is there build your own garage robotic assembly lines out there?

Tags: robotic-arm

I am new to robotics, and would like to build a smaller robotic arm than in manufacturing facilities.
I want a small robotic material handlers that can pick up or handle small objects around 12"x12"x12" objects. Essentially a small robotic assembly line in my garage.

Are there any kits I can purchase that deals with robotic assembly lines?
I was wondering has anyone dealt with this before any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of kickstarter campaigns for small low-cost robot arms.  It is interesting that there is a [delta robot](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1984252088/robot-army-starter-kit), a [scara arm](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/535786699/flxarm-low-cost-precision-robotic-arm), and a [parallelogram arm](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/ufactory/uarm-put-a-miniature-industrial-robot-arm-on-your).  However, I doubt they come with much software.  So you will probably have to do a lot of the controls yourself.